# Joint probability density function of N composite random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

If I got some random independent variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ with all with identical PDFs, for example $f_{X_i}(x_i) = e^{-x_i}$. Now I have some new set of random variables, where $S_k=\sum_i^k X_i, k=1,2,...n$, how do I find the joint PDF of these new variables, like the PDF of $S_1$?

I would think because $X_i$ are all independent that I should just multiple all the PDFs in order to find the joint PDF:
\begin{align}
f_{S_1}(x_1) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)\\
f_{S_2}(x_1,x_2) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot f_{X_2}(x_2)\\
&...\\
f_{S_n}(x_1,...,x_n) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot ...\cdot f_{X_n}(x_n)
\end{align}
or maybe because the way the random variable is defined they should be added:
\begin{align}
f_{S_1}(x_1) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)\\
f_{S_2}(x_1,x_2) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)+f_{X_2}(x_2)\\
&...\\
f_{S_n}(x_1,...,x_n) &= f_{X_1}(x_1)+...+f_{X_n}(x_n)
\end{align}

Which one of these is correct or am I way off?

Comment: The density of $S_n$ depends on the 1-dimensional variable $s$:   $f_{S_n}(s)$. So $f_{S_n}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ does not make sense.  We have $f_{S_n}(s) = d/ds P[S_n\leq s]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}_{X_{1}}\pars{x_{1}}\ldots
\mrm{f}_{X_{n}}\pars{x_{n}}\delta\pars{S - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n}x_{\ell}}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}_{X_{1}}\pars{x_{1}}\ldots
\mrm{f}_{X_{n}}\pars{x_{n}}\ \times
\\[2mm] &\
\bracks{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
\expo{\pars{S - \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n}x_{\ell}}s}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}\expo{Ss}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\mrm{f}_{X}\pars{x}\expo{-sx}\dd x}^{n}
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\label{1}\tag{1} \\ &
\end{align}
For example, with $\ds{\mrm{f}_{X}\pars{x} = \expo{-x}}$; (\ref{1}) is reduced to
\begin{align}
& \mbox{}
\\
&\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}{\expo{Ss} \over
\pars{x + 1}^{n}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} =
{1 \over \pars{n - 1}!}\lim_{s \to -1}\totald[n - 1]{\expo{Ss}}{s} =
\bbx{S^{n - 1}\expo{-S} \over \pars{n - 1}!} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Could you add a few more words about the context of these equations, I am having a hard time understanding them